# How to execute function k times?

Tags: scala

I have a function that generates random numbers as follows:

```scala
def genRandom(): Double = {
  //pass
  return something
}
```

Now, how do I call the above function to create k dimensional random vector? I have been thinking like

```
(0 to k).foreach {
  // FIXME Vec.append(getRandom())
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

How do i call this `genRandom` function k times and create a random vector out of it?

Comment: use: Vector.fill(10)(math.random)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible ways:

```
Vector.fill(k)(getRandom())
```

or:

```
(0 until k).map( _ => getRandom())
```

or:

```
 for ( i <- 0 until k ) yield getRandom()
```

Comment: To clarify, last two will repeat 1+k times. It should be (0 until k) or (0 to k-1) for repeating k times.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `foreach` delivers a `Unit`, not a collection from applying some argument(s) to a function. As aforementioned, use `map`, `for-yield` or `fill` over a `Vector`. On the latter, consider also `tabulate`, which allows for generating multidimensional vectors; in this context though,

```
Vector.tabulate(k)(_ => genRandom())
```

For the case of two dimensional (n times m) `Vector`,

```
Vector.tabulate(n,m)((_,_) => genRandom())
```